# how to retrieve rows from sql database containing same value of some particular column

Tags: database-table

I am working with grails. I have a class:

```
class Checkin_checkout {
    Date checkin_date
    Date checkout_date
    String time_duration
    int employee_id
}
```

I want to retrieve all the rows from database having same value of `employee_id`.
please help.

Comment: What is your database? What is your coding language?

Answer (score 0):

With Grails you can retrieve all rows from the database and then use `groupBy` to sort your entries by fields. So:

```
Checkin_checkout.list().groupBy { it.employee_id }
```